# Stack Overflow code snippets vs JSFiddle

Tags: discussion, support, bug, stack-snippets, error-message

Few minutes back I tried to answer a question on Stack Overflow [related to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45477436/displaying-html-elements-depending-on-which-link-is-clicked#)

So jumped to test the code first and fixed the stuff in stack code snippets and however it shows a console message.

[image]

Really? That's an empty line to my surprise. And digged further to the actual browser console and the same error message.

So just to check the same code, jumped to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sureshatta/pv8xdacq/) and code running fine. So just want to see what is Stack Overflow doing and read the error message again.

```
{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 52,
  "colno": 41
}
```

So it contains a filename too. Just quickly opened file name given and it's blank page.

Really loving Stack Overflow's code snippets and don't want to fiddle anymore. Is this a weird bug in code snippets or am I completely missing something which is obvious to check?

Comment: I get a different error: _ReferenceError: StateMachine is not defined_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yeah that is the original error in the posted code. I faced these  issues after fixing that.

Comment: Stack Snippets are not meant for interactive debugging. It's meant for the "Verifiable" part of Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 if (document.getElementById("Optimes") === null) {
   console.log('casing does matter')
 } else {
   console.log('Happy days!');
 }
```

```html
  <p id="OpTimes">You have clicked on OpTimes</p>
```

If you run into the error where the filename is *https://stacksnippets.net/js* you can be pretty sure the issue is in your own JavaScript. When I opened the dev console I was seeing the line on which the error occurred but it sometimes needs a reload to get in-sync.

You do get the error in JsFiddle but you have to get rid of the `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags and don't wrap your init code in

```
window.onload = function(){
StateMachine(0);
}
```

in the `onload` event. JSFiddle is already doing that and I'm pretty sure onload doesn't get called after being called.

Anyway, your JSFiddle is broken and so is your StackSnippet. There is no problem to fix for the Dev team.

Comment: That is fine if this is the answer for the actual code posted.   How does the error message from stack snippet helped you to trace this ? And besides that why there is no error at all in fiddle ?